# Language of Surahs in Salat

Tags: salat, quran-translation

My language is Bangla/Bengali. I know Surah's, I can read Arabic. But I don't understand the meaning. So, I read websites and books that translated surah's from Arabic to Bangla. Now my question is Can I use the translated Bangla version of Surah's in salat ?? I know, some translation can't be perfect. But, Can I use it ?

Answer (score 3):

No.  The Quran is to be read in Salat, and anything translated is not the Quran, rather more like a Tafseer to help those who don't understand, understand.  The Quran is in Arabic, anything other then that is not the Quran, so the Arabic should be read and nothing else.  And if you understand what it says by reading the translated/Tafseer of the Quran, then Alhamdulillah, you can read it in Salat with understanding.  May Allah forgive me of my mistakes, and guide us all.

[Here](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/111542) is some information in regards to the recitation of the Quran (in general) in a language other then Arabic.

Answer (score -1):

The people of the book that only focused on the meaning, lost the actual text. It is our responsibility to convey the text as well as the meaning of Quran to the world.

The only parts that must be in Arabic are Surah Fatiha and some part of Quran. Rest you can do in your own language as these are different duas. This creates an atmosphere of "talking to Allah" while praying. You should also know the meaning of the Arabic text too.